# Recursively execute all files with a specific extension via command line

Tags: windows, command-line

I need to execute all `.sfv` files recursively starting in a particular directory.
I have come up with the below so far.

`for /r "c:\mydir\" %x in (*.sfv) do start "%x"`

This code works; however, I need it to run each file in every 5 minutes upon execution?

Comment: Are you trying to delete or run each `.sfv` file? Please [edit] your title so we know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **This code works; however, I need it to run each file in every 5 minutes upon execution?**

Since your code already works and you show it and you only need to wait 5 minutes per each iteration in the loop to execute the file with the [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command after the first one executes, then you can use the [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) condition and run a `nul` [ping](http://ss64.com/nt/ping.html) to the loopback address using the `-n` switch and specify 300 seconds where each ping response is roughly a second; I always add one. I also added `""` as the first argument to the [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command to specify an empty title.

Additionally you could incorporate the [Timeout](http://www.howtogeek.com/196873/how-to-add-a-timeout-or-pause-in-a-batch-file/) command into the loop iteration and redirect to it with a 300 second wait period using the `/T` switch and specifying the `300` second value afterwards.

### Using the Ping Method

```
for /r "c:\mydir\" %x in (*.sfv) do start "" "%x" & ping 127.0.0.1 -n 301 > nul
```

### Using Timeout Delay Method

```
for /r "c:\mydir\" %x in (*.sfv) do start "" "%x" & timeout /T 30 > nul
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- [Ping](http://ss64.com/nt/ping.html)
- [Start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)
- [Timeout](http://www.howtogeek.com/196873/how-to-add-a-timeout-or-pause-in-a-batch-file/)